# Найти общие слова и отсортировать

Tags: python

Привет, я сейчас решаю элементарные задачки с checkio и по одной возник вопрос.

Задача такова:

> Даны две строки со словами, разделенными запятыми. Попробуйте найти
>   что общего между этими строками. Слова внутри каждой строки не
>   повторяются.
>
> Ваша функция должна находить все слова, которые появляются в обеих
>   строках. Результат должен быть представлен, как строка со словами
>   разделенными запятыми и отсортированными в алфавитном порядке.

Я сделал так:

```
def checkio(first, second):
    dbl = ""
    words = set(first.split(",") + second.split(","))

    for word in words:
        if word in first.split(",") and word in second.split(","):
            dbl += " ".join(word)
    return sorted(dbl)

checkio("one,two,three", "two,four,five,three")
```

Но, строка дополняется посимвольно и я не пойму почему. То есть вместо

```
two,three
```

он выводит

```
t,w,ot,h,r,e,e
```

Хочу разобраться почему так, подскажите куда смотреть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что Вы добавляете элементы в строку, а затем сортируете ее, вместо того, чтобы сортировать массив слов. Сортировка строки происходит посимвольно. Кроме того, результатом Вашей функции будет список из строк, каждая из которых содержит ровно один символ.

На самом деле, Вашу задачу можно решить гораздо проще, если воспользоваться стандартными функциями для работы с множествами, а именно [`intersection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection):

```
In [7]: def checkio(first, second):
   ...:     return ','.join(sorted(set(first.split(',')) & set(second.split(','))))
   ...: 

In [8]: checkio("one,two,three", "two,four,five,three")
Out[8]: 'three,two'
```

Стоит отметить, что в Вашем вопросе слова `two` и `three` не стоят в алфавитном порядке.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но если мы заменим dbl на список, то выходные данные все равно будут ['t', 'w', 'o', 't', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e'], хотя итерация уже должна идти по словам, а не по символам.

Comment: 'def checkio(first, second):
    dbl = []
    words = set(first.split(",") + second.split(","))

    for word in words:
        if word in first.split(",") and word in second.split(","):
            dbl += word
    return dbl'

Comment: А теперь уже в дело вступает реализация `+=` для списков. Дело в том, что эта функция ожидает перечислимый тип, и когда получает на вход строку, то радостно *перечисляет* ее, получая в итоге символы. Попробуйте заменить строки на обычные числа: `a = [1, 2, 3]; a += 4`. Вместо функции `__iadd__` можно использовать функцию [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: Теперь все понял. Спасибо.